# How to retrieve only user defined properties of a SQL Server database model

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, stored-procedures, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have db model like

```
class A
{ 
    public string a;
    public string b;
    public string c;
    . 
    .
    .
}
```

I only want to retrieve properties a and b on query from the database model A instead of retrieving the whole model A. Is there any way to do this in Entity Framework Core with a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var result = dbcontext.Entity
   .Select(x => new { x.ServerName, x.ProcessID, x.Username })
   .ToList();
```

I guess this will solve you issue!